# Parse and interact with obfuscated javascript

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize, web-scraping, deobfuscation

I'm trying to interact with a HTML 4.0 website which uses heavily obfuscated javascript to hide the regular HTML elements. What I want to do is to fill out a form and read the returned results, and this is proving harder to do than expected.

When I read the page using Firebug, it gave me the source code deobfuscated, and I can then use this to do what I want to accomplish. The Firebug output showed all the regular elements of a website, such as -tags and the like, which were hidden in the original source.

I've written the rest of my application in Python, using mechanize to interact with other web services, so I'd rather use an existing Python module to do this if that's possible. The problem is not only how to read the source code in a way mechanize can understand, but also how to generate the response which the web server can interpret. Could I use regular mechanize controls even though the html code is obfuscated?

In the beginning of my project I used pywebkitgtk instead of mechanize, but ditched it because it wasn't really implemented that well in python. Most functions are missing. Would that be a sensible method perhaps, to start up a webkit-browser which I read the HTML from, and use that with mechanize?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm really in a bind here. Thanks!

**Edit**: I tried dumping the HTML fetched from mechanize and opening that with pywebkitgtk, using load_html_string, and then evaluating the html that way. Unfortunately, since the document I'm trying to parse loads more resources dynamically, that scripts just stops waiting for resources to be loaded. Note that I can't use webkit to load the document itself since I use mechanize's CookieJar function to allow me to log in first.

I also tried dumping the HTML from webkit, which for some reason dumped the obfuscated javascript only, while displaying the website perfectly fine. If webkit could dump the deobfuscated javascript the way Firebug does, I could work with that and form a request according to the clean code..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to process the page, how about just use Firebug to figure out the names of the form fields, and then use httplib or whatever to send a request with the necessary fields and settings?

If it's sent using ajax, you should be able to determine the values being sent to the server in Firebug as well.

Comment: +1 for making it easier.  On a current project of my own I found incrementing one URL field for *very* similar HTTP requests using urllib was much easier than literally crawling pages with mechanize.

Comment: @Jani: I think I'll try this. It's annoying because I'm looking at Actionscript code which does exactly what I want to do, but I can't use the Adobe Air platform for my project. I'll get right on this. Thank you!

Comment: After thinking about this for a bit, I've realized a problem: The results I need to parse will be returned in obfuscated javascript code too, which unfortunately makes this solution impossible, the way I see it.

Comment: Unless the names of the variables/properties in the obfuscated code keep changing, you'd just need to figure out which is which and this should work. Sounds like some crazy piece of code you're trying to work out though... :D